# Using Go to connect to an IMAP server and issue commands

Tags: go, imap

I am trying to connect to an IMAP server with Go. I can connect and issue commands using `openssl` just fine:

```bash
openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.privateemail.com:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
test LOGIN myuser@email.com myp4ssw0rd
test OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY PREVIEW=FUZZY PREVIEW STATUS=SIZE SAVEDATE SEARCH=X-MIMEPART XDOVECOT LITERAL+ NOTIFY METADATA SPECIAL-USE QUOTA ACL RIGHTS=texk] Logged in
```

However, when I try the same in Go, I only get the pre-login message from the IMAP server. My code:

```golang
func main() {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "mail.privateemail.com:993", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    n, err := conn.Write([]byte("test LOGIN \"myuser@email.com\" \"myp4ssw0rd\"\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err.Error())
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 1000)
    n, err = conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
        return
    }

    log.Println(string(buf))
}
```

It produces the following output:

```bash
go run main.go
2023/02/09 10:06:12 * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
```

What do I need to do in order to send commands to the IMAP server with the`*tls.Conn`?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.2

> All interactions transmitted by client and server are in the form of
> lines, that is, strings that end with a CRLF.

`conn.Write([]byte("test LOGIN \"myuser@email.com\" \"myp4ssw0rd\"\r\n"))`

Comment: Unfortunately, `\r\n` at the end of the lines still produces the same outcome as described in my question.

Comment: Also, in the RFC it says: If instead, the server detected an error in the
        command, it sends a BAD completion response with a tag
        matching the command (as described below) to reject the
        command and prevent the client from sending any more of the
        command.

I do not get a BAD response back which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with writing to `conn`